# What's wrong with this proof? (Regular languages)

Tags: proof-verification, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

We want to show that for any fixed $n$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^n L_i$ is regular when all $L_i$ are regular.

I understand that this is only true for finite $n$. However, what's wrong with the following proof for infinite $n$ by induction?

Define $L^k$ to be $\bigcup_{i=1}^k L_i$.

For the basis step, we choose $n=1$. Then we have $L^k = L^1 = L_1$ which is regular by definition.

For the inductive hypothesis, let us assume that $L^k$ is regular with $k < n$. Then by the definitions of regular expressions, $L^k \bigcup L_{k+1}$ is also regular. But this is $L^{k+1}$ and so $L^{k+1}$ is regular.

Again, I understand why $n$ cannot be infinite. I am interested as to what point this proof is wrong.

Comment: The proof isn’t “wrong”, but it says nothing about an infinite union. What the induction shows is that $L^k$ is regular for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. An infinite union is different, and you really have to look at it as a whole object, rather than trying to construct it inductively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prove something for all ordinals, you usually need to do [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) and you have two inductive steps to deal with: *(i)* successor ordinals: from $\phi(\alpha)$ conclude $\phi(\alpha+1)$ and *(ii)* limit ordinals: from $\phi(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha < \lambda$, conclude $\phi(\lambda)$. If you only do the successor case, you have proved that $\phi(n)$ holds for all finite $n$, but you can't conclude that $\phi(\alpha)$ holds for any infinite $\alpha$ (the canonical counter-example is when $\phi(\alpha)$ is defined to mean $\alpha$ is finite).